# Clear widget kivy

Tags: kivy

I am newbie of kivy.
I have a button to refresh list items from database,
This is function bound to that button:

```
def refresh_account(self):
    self.ids.grid.clear_widgets()
    for d in self.listdata:
        self.acc_grid.add_row(d, body_alignment, col_size)
    scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(0.9, 0.9), size=(400, 50000), scroll_y=0, pos=(40, -30))
    scroll.clear_widgets()
    print "scroll children : ", scroll.children
    scroll.add_widget(self.acc_grid)
    scroll.do_scroll_y = True
    scroll.do_scroll_x = False
    self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.scroll)
```

I recieve an error :

> kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add "grid.DataGrid object at
>   0x7fd415756ce8", it already has a parent
>   "kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView object at 0x7fd413771b48"

Any reason for this? I have removed all widget by `scroll.clear_widgets()` and scroll children print out is "[]" ?

Answer (score 10):

The error is not that scroll already has children, but that the grid you are trying to add to it already has a parent. You haven't given enough information to actually debug the problem, but it is probably that `self.acc_grid` is not a child of `self.ids.grid` and therefore still has a parent after calling `clear_widgets`.

```
scroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(0.9, 0.9), size=(400, 50000), scroll_y=0, pos=(40, -30))
scroll.clear_widgets()
```

Also, the above snippet does nothing. You just instantiated the `ScrollView` so it naturally has no children. If you thought otherwise, perhaps this can help lead to your error.

(Also also, using `clear_widgets` is probably not really necessary, you could just update the existing widgets instead).

Comment: i cant find anything about update widget function in kivy , may be i must make it manually ?